# converting csv data to nested json format

Tags: python, json, dataframe, csv, nested

I have some csv data that need to be converted to specific json format.
I have written a code that works for some nested level but not as required

This is my csv data:

```
title   context answers question    id
tit1    con1    text1   que1    id1
tit1    con1    text2   que2    id2
tit2    con2    text3   que3    id3
tit2    con2    text4   que4    id4
tit2    con3    text5   que5    id5
```

my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('processedOutput.csv')
finalList = []
finalDict = {}
grouped = df.groupby(['context'])
for key, value in grouped:

    dictionary = {}

    j = grouped.get_group(key).reset_index(drop=True)
    dictionary['context'] = j.at[0, 'context']

    dictList = []
    anotherDict = {}
    for i in j.index:

        anotherDict['answers'] = j.at[i, 'answers']
        anotherDict['question'] = j.at[i, 'question']
        anotherDict['id'] = j.at[i, 'id']

        dictList.append(anotherDict)

    dictionary['qas'] = dictList

    finalList.append(dictionary)

import json
data = json.dumps(finalList)
```

whose output structure is fine but takes the last elem of grouped item only

```
[{"context": "con1",
  "qas": [
          {"answers": "text2", "question": "que2", "id": "id2"},
          {"answers": "text2", "question": "que2", "id": "id2"}
         ]
 },
 {"context": "con2", 
   "qas": [
           {"answers": "text4", "question": "que4", "id": "id4"},
           {"answers": "text4", "question": "que4", "id": "id4"}
          ]
 },
 {"context": "con3", 
   "qas": [
          {"answers": "text5", "question": "que5", "id": "id5"}
          ]
 }
]
```

want to make the data to be nested one more level with all fields as below:

```
[
 {
 "title": "tit1",
 "paragraph": [
  {
    "context": "con1",
    "qas": [
      {"answers": "text1","question": "que1","id": "id1"},
      {"answers": "text2","question": "que2","id": "id2"}
    ]}]
   },
  {
   "title": "tit2",
   "paragraph": [
     {
       "context": "con2",
       "qas": [
         {"answers": "text3","question": "que3","id": "id3"},
         {"answers": "text4","question": "que4","id": "id4"}

       ],
       "context": "con3",
       "qas": [
         {"answers": "text5","question":"que5", "id": "id5"}
       ]
     }
   ]
  }
]
```

stuck on this for very long, any suggestions will be great

Comment: tl;dr. But have you tried `df.to_json` method ?
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html

Comment: That will not give me json in grouped nested format as needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output data needs 3 levels of grouping: title, paragraph, and q&a's. I would recommend using `df.groupby(['title', 'context', 'answers'])` to drive the loop.

Then, within the loop, each group would constitute of one q&a dictionary (assuming
that `id` column contains unique values only). To build the higher level structure,
all it takes is some bookkeeping to detect level changes and add to the appropriate list and dictionary. We'll use more `groupby` levels to do this:

```
...
g1 = df.groupby(['title'])
for k1, v1 in g1:
    l2_para_list = []
    l4_qas_list = []
    g2 = v1.groupby(['context'])
    for k2, v2 in g2:
        g3 = v2.groupby(['answers'])
        for _, v3 in g3:
            qas_dict = {}
            qas_dict['answers'] = v3.answers.item()
            qas_dict['question'] = v3.question.item()
            qas_dict['id'] = v3.id.item()
            l4_qas_list.append(qas_dict)
        l3_para_dict = {}
        l3_para_dict['context'] = k2
        l3_para_dict['qas'] = l4_qas_list
        l4_qas_list = []
        l2_para_list.append(l3_para_dict)
        l3_para_dict = {}
    l1_title_dict = {}
    l1_title_dict['title'] = k1
    l1_title_dict['paragraph'] = l2_para_list
    finalList.append(l1_title_dict)
    l1_title_dict = {}
    l2_para_list = []
print(json.dumps(finalList))
...
```

Output (formatted for presentation)

```
[{"title": "tit1", "paragraph":
   [{"context": "con1",
    "qas": [{"answers": "text1", "question": "que1", "id": "id1"},
            {"answers": "text2", "question": "que2", "id": "id2"}]}]},
 {"title": "tit2", "paragraph":
   [{"context": "con2",
    "qas": [{"answers": "text3", "question": "que3", "id": "id3"},
            {"answers": "text4", "question": "que4", "id": "id4"}]},
    {"context": "con3",
    "qas": [{"answers": "text5", "question": "que5", "id": "id5"}]}]}]
```

Comment: Great thanks.. from this I can prepare qas dictinary, append it to context and made other dictionary but how will I group final json so that it will be merged based on title. i.e tit1 should contain all con1 and tit2 should contain con1 m con2 both and not separately as per df.

Comment: i.e how can I acheive this :         {"context": "con2", 
   "qas": [
           {"answers": "text4", "question": "que4", "id": "id4"},
           {"answers": "text4", "question": "que4", "id": "id4"}
          ]
 }

Comment: I've extended the code to make the group-levels logic explicit.